# Get column value from 2 strings

Tags: string, excel

I have 2 strings in columns: A1 and A2
one represents column letter (lets say:H) and the other one its number (lets say:5)
and I want to get the value of $A1$A2 (H5)
I've tried $A1$A2 and $A1&$A2
none worked.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `INDIRECT` for this:

```
=INDIRECT($A1&$A2)
```